# SQL/HQL Query: find object that has a list of objects that matchs some parameters

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, hql

I have these entities:

[image: ER Diagram]

Suppose I receive this `map<String,String>`:

> "gender": "male"
>
> "age": "30"

I need to find the campaigns that have a **TargetGroup that contains all these key/values from the map**.
Example:

```
Map<String,String> keyValueParameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
keyValueParameters.put("gender","male");
keyValueParameters.put("age","30");

List<Campaign> campaignsResult = getCampaigns(keyValueParameters);
Campaign aCampaign = campaignsResult.get(someIndex);
TargetGroup aTargetGroup = aCampaign.getTargetGroup();
List<TargetValue> targetValues = aTargetGroup.getTargetValues();
targetValues.get(x).getKey() //"gender"
targetValues.get(x).getValue() //"male"
targetValues.get(y).getKey() //"age"
targetValues.get(y).getValue() //"30"
targetValues.get(z).getKey() //some other key
```

Comment: I'm finding your question difficult to understand, and it seems complex enough that I shouldn't guess at your intentions. Can you please add table structures, sample data in the tables, and sample expected results to full illustrate your requirements.

Comment: So, there is a TargetGroup (or possibly more than one) that connects to every TargetValue, and you want information from the Campaigns that link to that TargetGroup.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: Please check the updated question.
EvilBob22> I think what you are saying is not my scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query returns list of target groups which have both key/value pairs. (2 in the HAVING section from conditions count

```
SELECT targetGroupID
FROM TargetGroup tg
     INNER JOIN TargetValue tv ON tg.targetGourpId=tv.targetGourpId
WHERE (tv.key='gender' and tv.value='male')
   OR (tv.key='age' and tv.value='30')
GROUP BY targetGroupID
HAVING COUNT(targetGroupID)>=2
```

Then we can use the query above to get appropriate campaigns

```
SELECT * 
FROM Campaign c
     INNER JOIN (the select above) as sub ON c.targetGroupID=sub.targetGroupID
```

I hardly possible with pure hibernate. HAVING is could be a problem. You can try to write your own hql for this.